# Converting standard file field to an Assets field with a remote source

Tags: assets, file-uploads, database, s3, aws

I have about 250 blog entries, each with a standard EE file field that points to a file on the same local server EE is running on. I've installed the [Assets](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/assets) add-on and set up an external source (an Amazon S3 bucket). I converted that standard file field to an Assets field pointing at that S3 bucket and it's working beautifully!

When creating a new blog post the file uploads to S3 without a hitch. Now onto the old posts:

What I need to do is to tell the Assets field to look for the image on S3 and not in the local filepath. I can manually move those images into place on S3, but I don't know what to do on the EE side to update the DB so Assets knows where to look.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is move the files to S3 from within Assets’ File Manager itself. If you do that, all of your existing data will automatically start pointing to the new location on S3.